# Use annotate to get percent give me resulte without comma 7/2 = 3 not 3.5

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, percentage

I want get percent value of :

```
nomberesteda * 100 / nomberhodor = 0.00
```

I use this queryset :

```
listilam = MediaSecParnt.objects.filter(date__range=[primary1, primary2]).values(
            'withsecondray__name','withdegrey__name','withsecondray_id','withdegrey_id')
.annotate(nomberhodor=Sum('nomberhodor'), nomberesteda=Sum('nomberesteda'), percent=((((F('nomberhodor')*100)/(F('nomberesteda'))))))
```

Here :

```
percent=((((F('nomberhodor')*100)/(F('nomberesteda'))))))
```

Percent value is returned without comma !

`nomberhodor` column is integer and same for nomberesteda

Here is the result:

```
<QuerySet [{'nomberhodor': 70, 'nomberesteda': 300, 'percent': 23},
{'nomberhodor': 64, 'nomberesteda': 150, 'percent': 42}, 
{'nomberhodor': 33, 'nomberesteda': 66, 'percent': 50}, 
{'nomberhodor': 50, 'nomberesteda': 200, 'percent': 25}, 
{'nomberhodor': 220, 'nomberesteda': 725, 'percent': 30},
{'nomberhodor': 567, 'nomberesteda': 900, 'percent': 63}, 
{'nomberhodor': 309, 'nomberesteda': 910, 'percent': 33}]>
```

it should be :

```
   <QuerySet [{'nomberhodor': 70, 'nomberesteda': 300, 'percent': 23.33},
{'nomberhodor': 64, 'nomberesteda': 150, 'percent': 42.66}, 
{'nomberhodor': 33, 'nomberesteda': 66, 'percent': 50.00}, 
{'nomberhodor': 50, 'nomberesteda': 200, 'percent': 25.00}, 
{'nomberhodor': 220, 'nomberesteda': 725, 'percent': 30.34},
{'nomberhodor': 567, 'nomberesteda': 900, 'percent': 63.00}, 
{'nomberhodor': 309, 'nomberesteda': 910, 'percent': 33.95}]>
```

Comment: `100.0`, not `100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [**`ExpressionWrapper`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.ExpressionWrapper) to specify the output format:

```
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, FloatField

.annotate(
    nomberhodor=Sum('nomberhodor'),
    nomberesteda=Sum('nomberesteda'),
    percent=ExpresssionWrapper(
        F('nomberhodor')*100/F('nomberesteda'),
        output_field=FloatField()
    )
)
```

for some databases, this is due to the type inference. In that case you can use `Cast`:

```
from django.db.models import FloatField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

.annotate(
    nomberhodor=Sum('nomberhodor'),
    nomberesteda=Sum('nomberesteda'),
    percent=Cast(F('nomberhodor'), output_field=FloatField()) *
        100/F('nomberesteda')
    )
)
```

Comment: this is not help it just give me the rusult with .0
all value come like that :
'percent': 42.0
'percent': 50.0}, 
{'percent': 25.0}, 
 'percent': 30.0},
 'percent': 63.0}, 
 'percent': 33.0}]>

Comment: @SalimFh: well if I run this locally, I get `[4.0, 2.0, 1.3333, 1.0, 0.8, 0.3333, 0.5714,...]` for some sample data.

Comment: nomberesteda = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=1, blank=1)
    nomberhodor = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=1, blank=1)
i really dont understabd why its not work with this models !

Comment: @SalimFh: I assume the database is PostgreSQL? This has its own type inference system. In that case you use `Cast`.

Comment: on server will use PostgreSQL
but i am on local test now and use sqllite

Answer (score 0):

thnks : Willem Van Onsem

```
percent=ExpressionWrapper(Cast(F('nomberhodor'), FloatField())/F('nomberesteda'),
    output_field=FloatField()))
    print(listilam):

<QuerySet [{'percent': 0.23333333333333334}, 
{'percent': 0.4266666666666667}, 
{'percent': 0.5}, { 'percent': 0.25},
 {'percent': 0.30344827586206896},
 {'percent': 0.63}, 
{'percent': 0.3395604395604396}]>
```

its work now